# find: excluding a subdir under OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, bash, find

I'd like to cast find on a dir excluding a subdir of its. I've found two very different examples on google and since they both do not even attempt to work, I assume either under OSX things something differs, or I'm doing something strange.

I'd like to do:

```
find here/ -name '*.xxx' -BUTNOT here/there/ -exec stuff {} \;
```

Using the examples I tried I either get an error, or 0 matches, or all matches.

I might need to exclude more than one subdir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have OS X available right now, but at least in Linux this works:

```
find . -name \*.xxx -o -path ./path/to/exclude -prune ...
```

---

To prune more than one dir, repeat the whole pattern `-o -path ... -prune`:

```
find . -name \*.xxx -o -path ./path/to/exclude1 -prune -o -path ./path/to/exclude2 -prune ...
```

Comment: Oooh initially it didn't work, then I noticed a problem was the trailing `/` in the path to exclude (while it causes no problems in the patch to search). Thanks!